# * Playtest feedback request* Puzzle 3

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You find the following four images (they are not in any particular order). Your solution is a street name (it will be well known to the players but might not to someone trying the puzzle here).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is familiarity with any non-English language necessary to solve this?

Comment: Not really. Players will have to understand what the shapes and images they are looking at are but character maps, and google image searches are allowed so that should help.

Comment: I've identified most of the things in each image, but I have no idea how anyone's supposed to find out what that near-circle symbol is. It seems basically impossible to find if you don't already know what it is.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the feedback. That one actually isn't a symbol but it might combine with something else to form one. :) Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Deusovi I took it to mean the ROT13(mra flzoby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Partial answer: maybe solved?

The lower-right symbols are

> Gurmukhi numerals from 1 to 4. These give an order for the four images.

Using that,

> the symbols are: the two halves of an @ sign, the "om" symbol from Devanagari, and the Hangul character "ik". This spells out ATOMIC.

Using *that*,

> each of the four numbers given is close to the atomic mass of a particular element. These element symbols are B, O, Re, N, making Boren Street the answer? This street name *exists*, but isn't particularly common, and I haven't figured out what to do with the rest (so this may not be the answer).
>
>  It's possible that the inverted IPA is supposed to clue something along the lines of "API" or "ELA". I'm not sure what the number 1 on a film reel(?) is supposed to be, though, and I don't see how the dolphin's tail and the one-way sign are particularly useful.

Comment: Well done! Indeed it's not a common name but the people solving this will be familiar with the name. For the second line (which you didn't need) ROT13(Gur frpbaq yvar fcryyf bhg "Jrvtug" nf vg tbrf jvgu gur svefg gb gryy gur cynlre gung gurl fubhyq hfr gur ngbzvp jrvtug. vgf "bar jnl" -1 nf vg vf n cubgb artngvir bs gur yrggre bar, gura n gnvy naq n artngvir vzntr bs na nyr. )